# Can we publish react-native-cli project (non-expo) to expo.io

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I created a react-native project using react-native-cli. I did not use expo-cli to create my project. Is there a way I can publish the app to expo.io.
I actually managed to publish the app, but the app does not work after scanning through expo-client on phone.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. An app must be started as an Expo project. They cannot be integrated into the Expo workflow at a later time, at least as a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

create your app with npx create-react-native-app .. this the best way to go.. and install the eas cli if you have native modules